# Como exibir uma foto do banco de Dados?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Não consigo exibir as fotos que estou mandando para o banco de dados.
Estou fazendo um sistema de comentário com foto e consegui manda-las para o banco de dados (mysql). Criei meu banco, depois minha tabela. Fiz a conexão e todos os itens da tabela estão recebendo seus dados. Só que a foto que não é exibida quando a chamo. Aparece apenas o nome da foto com a extensão. Como posso exibir a foto com os outros dados do comentário?
Segue o erro. No primeiro arquivo tenho o formulário e a chamada em php do  comentario. No segundo arquivo recebo os dados e envio para o banco de dados:
Consigo chamar todos os dados, mas a foto nao aparece, so seu nome.

Formulário:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Classificdos</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h1>Faça seu Comentario</h1>

    <?php // aqui inicia a busca de comentarios dentro do banco de dados. require 'conexao.php'; $buscaComentario=m ysql_query( "SELECT * FROM comentarios WHERE identificacao = '1' AND moderacao ='nao'"); while ($lista=m ysql_fetch_array($buscaComentario))
    { $nome=$ lista[ 'nome']; $site=$ lista[ 'site']; $comentario=$ lista[ 'comentario']; $avatar=$ lista[ 'avatar']; echo "
                            <p><strong>NOME: </strong> $nome </p>
                            <p><strong>SITE: </strong> $site </p>
                            <p><strong>COMENTÁRIO: </strong> $comentario </p>
                            <img>$avatar</img>
                            <hr/>

                        "; } ?>
    <hr/>

    <h3>Deixe seu comentário</h3>

    <form id="" action="cadastraComentario.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Preencha os Campos Abaixo:</legend>

        <label for="nome">NOME:</label>
        <input type="text" required id="nome" name="nome">
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <label for="email">E-MAIL:</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <label for="site">SITE (Opcional):</label>
        <input type="text" id="site" name="site">
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <label for="comentario">Deixe seu Comentário</label>
        <br/>
        <textarea name="comentario" id="comentario" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>

        <label id="escolher_foto" for="foto">Escolher uma Foto</label>
        <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar">

        <input type="submit" value="Comentar!">
        <br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="identificacao" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="moderar" value="nao" />
      </fieldset>
    </form>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

cadastrar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="seguraConteudo"> 

        <?php
        //error_reporting(0);

        require 'conexao.php';


        $nome =         $_POST['nome'];
        $email =        $_POST['email'];
        $site =         $_POST['site'];
        $comentario =   $_POST['comentario'];
        $identificacao= $_POST['identificacao'];
        $moderacao =    $_POST['moderar'];
        $arquivo =      $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
        $arquivoTemp =  $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];

        $pasta = "imagens/";
// Coloca a foto em uma pasta diretorio
        move_uploaded_file($arquivoTemp, $pasta);


        $headers = "Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8";
        $headers = "From: $email";
        $para    = "teste@servidor.com";
            $mensagem = "De: $nome";
            $mensagem .= "E-mail: $email";
            $mensagem .= "Site: $site";
            $mensagem .= "Comentario: $comentario";



        $envia = mail($para, "Comentário Efetuado no site", $mensagem, $headers);


        $insere = ("INSERT INTO comentarios (id, nome, email, site, comentario, identificacao, moderacao,avatar ) VALUES ('NULL', '$nome', '$email', '$site', '$comentario', '$identificacao', '$moderacao', '$arquivo')");

        $insereBanco = mysql_query($insere);

            echo "<p><strong>$nome</strong>, seu comentário foi efetuado com sucesso e aguarda liberação. Obrigado!";
            echo "<p><a href='Sistema_comentarios.php'>Voltar</a></p>";

        ?>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que pude observar no seu código, você está fazendo:

```
$avatar=$lista[ 'avatar'];

<img>$avatar</img>
```

Como você está armazenando uma imagem, o conteúdo da variável `$avatar` é uma url, logo você deve fazer assim:

```
<img src=$avatar></img>
```

Pelo que entendi é isso.

---

Seu problema está na árvore do caminho para as imagens, no banco de dados só tem uma string que é o nome e a extensão, logo um exemplo de organização de arquivos:

Esse é o conteúdo do diretório `pastadomeuprojeto`

```
-- index.html
-- pagina01.html
-- pagina02.html
-- /images
   -- logo.png
   -- decoracao.png
   -- frutas.jpg
-- /css
   -- home.css
-- /js
   -- effects.js
```

Em geral essa é a organização de arquivos de um projeto web, se eu estiver quero `frutas.jpg` dentro da minha página pagina01.html, minha url será `/images/frutas.jpg`, caso não funcione pode ser sem a primeira barra `/`, se ainda não funcionar use o caminho completo:

`C://../pastadomeuprojeto/images/frutas.jpg`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta leandro, tentei isto então mas não deu certo, mas acredito que é por ai mesmo, pelo menos agora ja aparece aquela pequena imagem de erro, de que ali tem uma imagem mas não foi exibida. Tem algo que estou errando e nao sei.

Comment: Imprima o conteúdo da sua variável $avatar, provavelmente o caminho da imagem estará errado, tente usar o caminho absoluto ou algo do tipo

Comment: dei um echo "$avatar"; e voltou a aparecer apenas o nome da imagem, do mesmo jeito que ela ta no banco de dados.

Comment: você tem que completar o caminho com as pastas que ela se encontra, se usar só o nome dela, ela tem que estar na raiz do documento html que você faz essa requisição

Comment: fiz este codigo vindo de dois tutorias diferentes, sou iniciante e alugamas coisa preciso de ajuda. Descilpa qualquer coisa entao. Criei a variavel $pasta = "imagens/", nao sei como buscar este caminho agora e nem. como ficaria?

Comment: editei a resposta vê se ajudou

Comment: perfeito leandro percebi bem, mas na minha pasta do meu projeto nao ha nenhuma pasta imagem, apareceu apenas um arquivo chamado imagem, do tipo ficheiro, sem extensão com 3MB. Eu teria que ter criado uma pasta chamada imagem assim quando criei a variavel $pasta ="imagem/"; ? Onde estão as fotos agora que enviei pro banco? nao consigo acha-las, para buscar o caminho. o estranho é este arquivo que te falei chamado imagem que apareceu na pasta deste projeto

Comment: Provavelmente você tem que configurar a variável $_FILES[], ela que recebe o arquivo no upload, de uma olhada nesse link: http://tableless.com.br/upload-de-arquivos-com-php/

Comment: Muito obrigado Leandro este tutorial resolveu os problemas que eu tinha no codigo, a foto esta a ser substituída e toda hora ele ensinou a mudar o nome. E a img deve ser exibida assim <img src='uploads/$avatar'>

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado :)